# how to make a certain values of a column value to zero based on another column' value in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

how to make a certain values of a column value to zero based on another column' value which is a list in Python

```
S.No    Num_1   Num_2   Num_3   Num_4   Num_5   id  Final
0   2   4   2   1   1   1   1.1
1   2.5 4.6 2.7 1.2 1.1 1   1.2
2   2   4   2   1   1   1   1.3
3   2.5 4.6 2.7 1.2 1.1 2   1.4
4   2   4   2   1   1   2   1.5
5   2.5 4.6 2.7 1.2 1.1 2   1.6
6   2   4   2   1   1   3   1.7
7   2.5 4.6 2.7 1.2 1.1 4   1.8
8   2   4   2   1   1   4   1.9
9   2.5 4.6 2.7 1.2 1.1 5   2
10  2   4   2   1   1   5   2.1
11  2.5 4.6 2.7 1.2 1.1 6   2.2
12  2   4   2   1   1   6   2.3
13  2.5 4.6 2.7 1.2 1.1 6   2.4
14  2   4   2   1   1   6   2.5
15  2.5 4.6 2.7 1.2 1.1 7   2.6
16  2   4   2   1   1   7   2.7
17  2.5 4.6 2.7 1.2 1.1 7   2.8
18  2   4   2   1   1   7   2.9
19  2.5 4.6 2.7 1.2 1.1 8   3
20  2   4   2   1   1   8   3.1
21  2.5 4.6 2.7 1.2 1.1 8   3.2
22  2   4   2   1   1   10  3.3
23  2.5 4.6 2.7 1.2 1.1 10  3.4
```

and `id = [2,4,5,6,8]`

wherever my id is list the final value should be 0 (ZERO)

How do I do this in python or Pandas?

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.where`

```
import numpy as np

id_ = [2,4,5,6,8]  # as id is a keyword in Python

df['Final'] = np.where(df['id'].isin(id_), 0, df['Final'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) your series:

```
ids = [2, 4, 5, 6, 8]
df['Final'] = df['Final'].mask(df['id'].isin(ids), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
id_ = [2,4,5,6,8]

df['Final'].loc[df['id'].isin(id_)] = 0
```